# return object of operator= overloading in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this, operator-keyword

What is the difference between returning `*this` or the given argument in implementation of operator= in C++? Is using one of them better or more useful? if yes, why?

```
   class Object {
   public:
      Object operator=(Object Obj) {
         return *this;
      }
   }
```

vs.

```
   class Object {
   public:
      Object operator=(Object Obj) {
         return Obj;
      }
   }
```

Comment: You should be returning a reference to the current object, not a brand new object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 1):

`X& operator=( X const& ) { return *this; }` matches the semantics of `=` on an `int`. The other suggestions you gave do not.  When in doubt match the semantics of `int`.